# can't change the date/time parsed column to CST then to UTC In R

Tags: r, parsing, csv, lubridate

I have a table of info including date and time. the years, months, days, time(HHMM) are in separate column.The time is in CST. I need to put them all in one col. and change the time to UTC. I need to do this using the lubridate.

The below is what I am trying to do. but always comes with an error

```
data<-read.csv("StormEvents_details_d1950_d2014.csv", header=T, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

data1<-mutate(data1, begin_date=str_c(begin_year, "-", begin_month, "-", begin_day, "  ", begin_time))
data1<-mutate(data1, end_date=str_c(end_year, "-", end_month, "-", end_day, "  ", end_time))

data1$begin_date<-ymd_hm(data1$begin_date)
data1$begin_date<-ymd_hms(data1$begin_date, tz="CST6CDT")

Error: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?
Error during wrapup: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?
```

Comment: Suggest to provide sample data using `dput()`

Comment: I am getting this too. Interesting that no one has solved it.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably related to this bug:
https://github.com/hadley/lubridate/issues/224

I don't think the OP is interested anymore, but this error can be reproduced with this code:

```
library(lubridate)
dmy_hm("3/10/2010 1:59",tz="Australia/Melbourne")  # good
dmy_hm("3/10/2010 2:00",tz="Australia/Melbourne")  # this time never existed
dmy_hm("10/3/2010 2:00",tz="US/Pacific")           # this time never existed
```

Note that in spring the clocks are adjusted to DST by changing the time from 2 AM to 3 AM, thus there are 60 minutes every year that do not exist.

Obviously it should not error, out but I tried this with the latest `lubridate` (1.3.3) (23 April 2015) and the bug is still there.

There are two workarounds that I can see.

1. Convert the with `ymd_hms` data as UCT (it does not have a DST adjustment)
2. Then subtract the timezone difference from those times using `difftime`.
3. Change the timezone to the timezone you need for display with  `attr(ddf$time, "tzone") <- "US/Pacific"`

Or...

1. Read the data into a character array.
2. Subset the "bad" character out of the data set.
3. Then convert the character data with `ymd_hms` (or whatever)

Hope this helps someone.